# What's a decent SFTP command-line client for windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, sftp

Most of the windows SFTP clients (like FileZilla) seem to be GUI-based.  I need something I can call from batch files.

Comment: Isn't sftp just ssh. I think you really want something that is capable of scp or rsync via ssh.

Comment: wsftp: http://docs.ipswitch.com/WS_FTP125/Help/Tools/English/index.htm?17981.htm?toc.htm

Answer (score 49, accepted):

pscp and psftp are very customizable(options) and light weight. Open source to boot.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: Used it with a "ppk" and a mounted share on windows without issues !

Answer (score 16):

WinSCP has the command line functionality:

```
c:\>winscp.exe /console /script=example.txt
```

where scripting is done in `example.txt`.

See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

Refer to http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation_advanced for details on how to use a scripting language such as Windows command interpreter/php/perl.

FileZilla does have a command line but it is limited to only opening the GUI with a pre-defined server that is in the Site Manager.

Answer (score 6):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) + sftp/scp natrually

Comment: I need to execute it from a batch file.  Cygwin is out.

Comment: You can call Cygwin executables from a batch file.

Answer (score 6):

WinSCP can be called from batch file:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /console
```

Example commands:

```
option batch on 
option confirm off  
option transfer binary 
open sftp://username@hostname:port -hostkey="ssh-rsa "
```

Answer (score 1):

www.bitvise.com - sftpc is a good command line client also.

Answer (score 1):

LFTP is great, however it is Linux only. You can find the Windows port [here](http://nwgat.ninja/lftp-for-windows/). Never tried though.

Achtunq, it uses Cygwin, but everything is included in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

[bitvise tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) works really well

Answer (score 0):

This little application does the job for me. I could not find another CLI based client that would access my IIS based TLS/SSL secured ftp site:
http://netwinsite.com/surgeftp/sslftp.htm

Answer (score -2):

Filezilla is great and it can support [command line arguments](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client)).

Comment: You're going to want to put in/escape your closing parenthesis.

Comment: No, the command line arguments are just for opening the UI already connected to a certain server.  I want to script it with a batch file, the entire process has to be command-line driven.